# Gettting memory error when resizing CIFAR10 images

Tags: python, image-processing, google-colaboratory

```
def load_cifar10_data(img_rows, img_cols):

    # Load cifar10 training and validation sets
    (X_train, Y_train), (X_valid, Y_valid) = cifar10.load_data()

    # Resize training images
    X_train = np.array([cv2.resize(img, (img_rows,img_cols)) for img in X_train[:,:,:,:]])
    X_valid = np.array([cv2.resize(img, (img_rows,img_cols)) for img in X_valid[:,:,:,:]])

    # Transform targets to keras compatible format
    Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(Y_train, num_classes)
    Y_valid = np_utils.to_categorical(Y_valid, num_classes)

    X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
    X_valid = X_valid.astype('float32')

    # preprocess data
    X_train = X_train / 255.0
    X_valid = X_valid / 255.0

    return X_train, Y_train, X_valid, Y_valid
X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = load_cifar10_data(224, 224)
```

Getting memory error
if i run this in google colab the RAM just increases and the notebook just crashes

Comment: Please format the code by selecting it and typing `ctrl-k` [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [more Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because you're using more than the ram limit available on GoogleColab. CIFAR-10 has 60000 images approx. This would approximately be the equivalent size of (60 000 x 8 (float = 8 bytes) x 224 x 224 x 3 (if image in RGB) )  = 72253440000 bytes = 67.29 GB. There's a limit of 12 GB of RAM on GoogleColab. You can either resize your images to a smaller size or reduce the number of images.